# How to make this 2 step query solution better

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Query is made in MS Access :

I show now a simplified example of my problem.

I have one table Members

```
Name/age/nickname

- Tom/12/wolf
- Chris/11/ranger
- Phil/14/H-man
- Chris/16/walker
- Chris/18/Mo
```

Goal: How many times a name occurs , but only count when the nickname had an "a" in it.

I needed 2 queries;
Step1:

```
SELECT Members.Name, Members.Age, Members.Nickname
FROM Members
WHERE (((Members.Nickname) Like "*A*"));
```

Step2:

```
SELECT Step1.Name, Count(Step1.Age) AS AantalVanAge
FROM Step1
GROUP BY Step1.Name;
```

Result

```
- Chris 2
- Phil 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in a single query using:

```
select t.name, count(*) as AantalVanAge
from members t
where t.nickname like "*A*"
group by t.name
```

Comment: Yes. @Marvy may have oversimplified the problem.

Comment: Ok ..I needed to put where in de group by field in access. That was new for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use your 1st query as a subquery in the 2nd step:

```
SELECT t.Name, Count(t.Age) AS AantalVanAge
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Age
  FROM Members
  WHERE Nickname Like "*A*"
) AS t
GROUP BY t.Name;
```